# Difference between airDF[is_vacation, airDF$ArrDelay] (where is_vacation is a logical vector) and airDF[is_vacation, 'ArrDelay']

Tags: r, data-science

What is the difference between (`is_vacation` is a logical vector):

```
tapply(X = airDF[is_vacation, airDF$ArrDelay], airDF[is_vacation, airDF$FromTo], mean, na.rm = TRUE)

tapply(X = airDF[is_vacation, 'ArrDelay'], airDF[is_vacation, 'FromTo'], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In the first option i got error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(airDF, is_vacation, airDF$FromTo) : no columns
> were selected.

Comment: The first one should be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is wrong, as instead of the column names or index, it is the column values used in the `j` where as second option is fine

```
 tapply(mtcars[1:5, 'mpg'], mtcars[1:5, 'gear'], mean)
    3     4 
20.05 21.60
```